# Pull based queue for displaying error message

Tags: java, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, queue

I need to push errors in a queue and display them on a screen. Once the user ack the error, that message should disappear from the screen else if the user doesn't click the ack button, message should still be visible on the screen, anytime we load the screen. Required throughput is not more. Thus need pull based queue. any suggestions on which queue to use. RabbitMQ or Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

If you consume a message from a queue (to display a message to the user) then by default it is removed from the queue (physically deleted). This doesn't meet your requirement that the user needs to manually acknowledge the message first.

If a Kafaka Consumer consumes a message from a topic, by default the offset for that message is also acknowledged as processed. The message is still there in the Topic (until it's deleted after the retention period is met), but the offset is advanced to the next message after each is consumed.

I don't think either of these approaches meet what you're looking for. It seems like you need a database table of messages with:

a) an column representing whether the message has been acknowledged or not

b) an FK for the user id (so you know what messages are for what user, assuming your system has more than a single user)